# How to get the latitude and longitude of an image in sdcard to my application?

Tags: android, gps

From my application I can open gallery. Is there any way to get latitude and longitude of any selected image in gallery to my application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You Should Go with  [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class to read various EXIF metadata from Images:

Example :

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
```

**Edited :**

Now Here you will get lat-long as Below format.

**lat = 30/1,12/1,34/1,
long=81/1,22/1,41/1**

To Convert this into Real Values [this Blog](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/01/convert-exif-gps-info-to-degree-format.html) Helped Me.

we need to do conversion from degree, minute, second form to GeoPoint form.

By Below Way you can Do it.

```
 String LATITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
 String LATITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
 String LONGITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
 String LONGITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);

 // your Final lat Long Values
 Float Latitude, Longitude;

 if((LATITUDE !=null)
   && (LATITUDE_REF !=null)
   && (LONGITUDE != null)
   && (LONGITUDE_REF !=null))
 {

  if(LATITUDE_REF.equals("N")){
   Latitude = convertToDegree(LATITUDE);
  }
  else{
   Latitude = 0 - convertToDegree(LATITUDE);
  }

  if(LONGITUDE_REF.equals("E")){
   Longitude = convertToDegree(LONGITUDE);
  }
  else{
   Longitude = 0 - convertToDegree(LONGITUDE);
  }

 }

private Float convertToDegree(String stringDMS){
 Float result = null;
 String[] DMS = stringDMS.split(",", 3);

 String[] stringD = DMS[0].split("/", 2);
    Double D0 = new Double(stringD[0]);
    Double D1 = new Double(stringD[1]);
    Double FloatD = D0/D1;

 String[] stringM = DMS[1].split("/", 2);
 Double M0 = new Double(stringM[0]);
 Double M1 = new Double(stringM[1]);
 Double FloatM = M0/M1;

 String[] stringS = DMS[2].split("/", 2);
 Double S0 = new Double(stringS[0]);
 Double S1 = new Double(stringS[1]);
 Double FloatS = S0/S1;

    result = new Float(FloatD + (FloatM/60) + (FloatS/3600));

 return result;


};



@Override
public String toString() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return (String.valueOf(Latitude)
   + ", "
   + String.valueOf(Longitude));
}

public int getLatitudeE6(){
 return (int)(Latitude*1000000);
}

public int getLongitudeE6(){
 return (int)(Longitude*1000000);
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is getExitTag...?

Comment: @SREEJITH :Oh.thanks for pointing it out. Actually i have Used the Method getExitTag(..) here. but Edited My Answer. you just have to use  exif.getAttribute(TYPE); Method.

Comment: I am getting a value 10/1,16/1,3/1 instead of latitude.

Comment: Pls tell me why it is like this

Comment: @SREEJITH: edited my answer you can check it. and let me know if it will works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your code .And also there is small error in the code which I have edited. Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya I am getting error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.package/com.package.publicconnect.LevelFirst}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float java.lang.Float.floatValue()' on a null object reference` I have written this in a separate class and call in `onActivityResult()` i am taking picture so i want to get the lat and long of that image. i am passing filename in the `exif..` and passing it to constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798250/how-to-get-location-and-other-information-from-image-in-android

Comment: Not working solution! exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE) returns 0.0 values for latitude and longitude always. But coordinates are exists in image - in image viewer I can see this info. Anybody can help with issue?

Comment: @Vitaly path is incorrect format, did you get image from gallery?

Answer (score 13):

You can actually use a "buildin" function:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
float[] latLong = new float[2];
boolean hasLatLong = exif.getLatLong(latLong)
if (hasLatLong) {
    System.out.println("Latitude: " + latLong[0]);
    System.out.println("Longitude: " + latLong[1]);
}
```

Maybe is something new, but I think is much more convenient than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)
val exif = inputStream?.let { it1 -> ExifInterface(it1) }
if (exif != null) {
   val latLong = FloatArray(2)
   if (exif.getLatLong(latLong)) {
      Log.d("Debug", "lat ${latLong[0]} long ${latLong[1]}")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `exif.getLatLong(float[])` is now deprecated, you can use a better method which returns a `double[]` :

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(file);
double[] latlng = exifInterface.getLatLong();
if (latlng != null) {
    Double currentLatitude = latlng[0];   
    Double currentLongitude = latlng[1];
    Log.d("Debug", "Exif : latitude: " + currentLatitude + ", longitude: " + currentLongitude)  
}
```

Happy coding.