# Enable camera settings -- android

Tags: android, performance

Is that possible to enable **camera setting** pragrammatically? I want to enable camera setting page programmatically and enable the user to do something from that page. I have searched so far, cant able to get proper reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want to open the Camera preferences activity and set location tagging on, in a similar way that Google Maps directs the user to a system preferences activity for  switching on GPS. Unfortunately this isn't possible for the camera application, mainly because the camera app isn't standard across android devices.

Personally I have three camera apps on phone, not including apps like Eyem and Instagram, and I don't think this is unusual.  None of them have the same activity for setting the preferences, and even the built in app doesn't have a standard preferences activity.

If you want to go down this route the best you can probably do is first check for location services being available (see [How to check if Location Services are enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311834/android-dev-how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled) for an example if you are unsure)  before invoking the intent to take the  picture. Direct the user to turn them on if necessary and also, warn them that you require location tagging turned on in their camera app of choice.

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about `Camera.Parameters` when you say settings, yes of course you can.
All possibilities are listed here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html
You will have to write your own user interface to get the desired parameters and pass them to the `camera`-objekt before you start a `preview`.

Comment: Thanks for replies, I want to enable the camera geo tagging pragmatically. Is this possible to do. I'm searching for a while, i cant able to get proper solution. Pls help me

Comment: check the link for setGpsLatitude() / setGpslogitude(). But be aware of that you will have to get those values beforehand.

Comment: From the Android documentation: [Training: Making Your App Location-Aware](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html), specifically, [Retrieving the Current Location](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)